# Finding difference in PHP timestamp?

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I have a timestamp like this, I'm trying to calculate how long between created_at and closed_at, so how long the session lasted.

```
{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($clientLogin->closed_at - $clientLogin->created_at)->diffForHumans() }}
```

Although it wont let me compare it?

> Object of class Illuminate\Support\Carbon could not be converted to
>   int (View:
>   C:\Users\admin\Desktop\workspace\document_root\resources\views\user\logs.blade.php)

Comment: Try: `$created_at_date = $clientLogin->created_at;  $difference = $clientLogin->closed_at->diffForHumans($created_at_date);`

Comment: I need it in diffForHumans unfortunately.

Comment: I have updated it to `diffForHumans`

Comment: diffForHumans isn't a constant value @PrashantPrajapati it changes as the date changes, maybe you should look that up?

Comment: @HirenGohel `$clientLogin->closed_at->diffForHumans($clientLogin->created_at)` causes an error: `Call to a member function diffForHumans() on null`

Comment: Have you value of `$clientLogin->created_at`??

Answer (score 3):

Try the below code :

```
Carbon\Carbon::parse($clientLogin->getOriginal('closed_at'))->diffForHumans(Carbon::parse($clientLogin->getOriginal('created_at')), true);
```